# Regex - Match words with shared spaces

Tags: regex, spaces

How do I match specified words in a sentence?
If I have the sentence "lord of the rings" and want to remove "of" and "the" how do I write the regex?

I don't want it to match anything in for example "don't match them" or "don't match often". It should match when "the" or "of" is in the beginning or end of the row as well.

The problem I encountered is when the words follow each other like in the example with "lord of the rings". When they share a space so to say.

The best I could manage is something like this:

```
/^(the|of) | (the|of)$| (of|the) /gmi
```

But it doesn't solve all my problems.

Comment: Damn ! i was about to post here @WiktorStribiżew `:D`

Comment: How about `\b(of|the)\b`?

Comment: word boundaries would be more better

Comment: `of` is unlikely to appear at the start of string or next to punctuation, `the` should appear in similar context, but can appear at the start of the string. So, `/(?:^|\s+)(?:of|the)(?!\S)/gi` looks viable here, but when `The` appears at the start, the string still needs to be trimmed from whitespace.

Comment: *Of the two of us, who is going to turn his comment into an answer?* @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: `\b(of|the)\b` works great. Easy to read and expand if I need to add more words. If you post this as an answer I will accept it. @Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect task for word boundaries

```
\b(of|the)\b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lookahead group `(?= )` [[doc](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)]:

```
/^(the|of) | (the|of)$| (of|the)(?= )/gmi
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/Bo4Ur1/1

Answer (score 0):

Would `/(of\s.*the\s)/gmi` work? Or did I misunderstand what you're trying to do?
This will find everything between the first 'of ' to the last 'the ' in your sentence.

Comment: This isn't really what I was looking for. Sorry if my post was not clear but I want it to match even it "of" and "the" doesn't come in that exact order.